# Right click to create shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, shortcuts, context-menu

I have been used Windows 7 for a while. However, the right click New -> Shortcut that was not there. How I get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

- Open the location containing the item that you want to create a shortcut to.
- Right-click the item, and then click Create shortcut. The new shortcut appears in the same location as the original item.
- Drag the new shortcut to the desired location.

Your issue seems like a faulty OS; There is a [fix here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/172092-new-shortcut-fix.html) (it appears it corrects the registry entries which it assumes must be wrong) although I have not tried it and would recommend creating a system restore point first!

Comment: Yes. Or, right-drag the icon to the new location. On releasing the right mouse button, you get a pop-up menu.

Comment: There's also rightclick -> send -> to desktop, which will create a shortcut on the desktop.